# How to create a right-click context menu for a button in WPF

Tags: wpf, button, contextmenu

i know how to create a left-click context menu for a button, but I am not too sure how to do it for a right click? (i.e. how to specify that the context menu should appear on a right-click, not a left click).

Many thanks.

Comment: are you sure you don't have the question reversed? contextmenu is triggered by a right-click by default, to trigger on a left-click is what takes extra work (don't know why you'd want that on a button though?)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Here is a sample:

```
<Button Content="button" Name="btn" Width="100">
    <Button.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Cut"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Copy"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Paste"/>
        </ContextMenu>
    </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>
```

[image]